# Create invalid UTF8 string

Tags: javascript, utf-8

Is it possible to create an invalid UTF8 string using Javascript?

Every solution I've found relies `String.fromCharCode` which generates `undefined` rather than an invalid string. I've seen mention of errors being generated by ill-formed UTF8 string (i.e. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket#send()) but I can't figure out how you would actually create one.

Comment: The error mentioned there is not about UTF-8 strings, and javascript typically does not use UTF-8 to represent strings internally.

Comment: @pvg: Thanks for pointing out the mistake. Not sure why I assumed UTF8 was the javascript encoding. My question should have been more specific: How can you create a string that contains unpaired surrogates?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure and the docs seem pretty vague although it's possible to reach into the bowels of javascript strings and do a lot of strange things without things instantly catching fire. https://i.imgur.com/sWVE0IY.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to generate an invalid UTF-8 string with JavaScript is to take an emoji and remove the last byte.

For example, this will be an invalid UTF-8 string:

```
const invalidUtf8 = ''.substr(0,5);
```

Answer (score 3):

A string in JavaScript is a counted sequence of UTF-16 code units. There is an implicit contract that the code units represent Unicode codepoints. Even so, it is possible to represent any sequence of UTF-16 code units—even unpaired surrogates.

I find `String.fromCharCode(0xd801)` returns the replacement character, which seems quite reasonable (rather than `undefined`). Any text function might do that but, for efficiency reasons, I'm sure that many text manipulations would just pass invalid sequences through unless the manipulation required interpreting them as codepoints.

The easiest way to create such a string is with a string literal. For example, `"\uD83D \uDEB2"` or `"\uD83D"` or `"\uDEB2"` instead of the valid `"\uD83D\uDEB2"`.

`"\uD83D \uDEB2".replace(" ","")` actually does return `"\uD83D\uDEB2"` (`""`) but I don't think you should count on anything good coming from a string that isn't a valid UTF-16 encoding of Unicode codepoints.

Comment: No good coming from it is exactly what I hoped ;) I'm trying to reliably generate an error in a websocket for testing purposes. Unfortunately the string literal you offered gets transformed into two replacement characters separated by a space (in Chrome at least). Thanks for the information though. It was still useful to know.